# Appending columns of DataFrame to other DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two `DataFrames` with only one row and distinct columns:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('ABC'))
df1.loc[0] = [1,2,3]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('DE'))
df2.loc[0] = [18,3]
```

Now I would like to append the column of `df2` to the right of `df1`. I have tried the following:

```
temp = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index()], axis=1)
```

The problem here is that also two `index` columns are added which I don't want. If I add `ignore_index = True` then the index columns are not added but all column names are removed. That is also not what I want.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: what's wrong with `pd.concat([df1,df2] , axis=1)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang It creates a DataFrame with two rows in my case.

Comment: it creates one in my system. Maybe you have different indexes, e.g. `df2.loc[1] = [18,3]`. Try to pass `drop=True` in your `reset_index()` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably set the index of `df2` to be the same as `df1`

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('ABC'))
df1.loc[0] = [1,2,3]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('DE'))
df2.loc[0] = [18,3]
```

This will keep the index of `df1`

```py
df2.index = df1.index

temp = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

if you don't care about the index at all you can reset and drop the index

```py
temp = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True), df2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```